# How to extends defensively coded implementation? E.g. vert.x CorsHandlerImpl

Tags: java, vert.x

There are defensively coded libraries like vert.x. Using interface with static factory way to return implementation. Developer could use their implementation, but when it is not **exactly** what is needed - it is not possible to extend it. Unfortunatelly, it even bind implementation **into** interface. Why?

What is recomended way to extends such classes? There has to be other way than copy whole class and rewrite only few needed lines...

E.g.: vert.x implementation of io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler

```
public interface CorsHandler {
  static CorsHandler create(String allowedOriginPattern) {
    return new CorsHandlerImpl(allowedOriginPattern);
  }
  ...
}


public class CorsHandlerImpl implements CorsHandler {
  private boolean isValidOrigin(String origin) {
  }
  ...
}


public class MyCorsHandler implement/extends CorsHandler/impl {
  @Override
  protected boolean isValidOrigin(String origin) {
    // my changes 
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to override a private method ?

Comment: Yes, in this example it is enought. In another case, it is needed to "override" constructor or field, and the worst case is when target class use another "non-public" class.

Comment: Constructor **can't** be overriden, nor anything `private`. The saffest way to extend a existing class is to [decorate it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (similar to the Adapter pattern described by Davide Lorenzo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to wrap a class instead of extending it and change only methods that need a different implementation.

This solution is called [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

> In software engineering, the adapter pattern is a software design pattern (also known as Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Decorator pattern) that allows the interface of an existing class to be used as another interface.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) **It is often used to make existing classes work with others without modifying their source code**.

Consider that extending existing classes written by others is not a good idea generally. Infact in a following release their internal implementation can change and that changes can be reflected on extended classes changing their behaviour in a way that sometime is not predictable.

Here an example showing that:

Imagine that you need to extend a ArrayList with a custom implementation to log all added items.

Actually you can rewrite the add and addAll methods as follow:

```
public void add(E e) {
   System.out.println("add item " + e);
   super.add(e);
}

public void addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
   for (E e : c) {
       System.out.println("add item " + e);
   }
   super.addAll(c);
}
```

This works because the internal implementation of `addAll` don't call `add`. But if the implementation of `addAll` changes with a loop over the collection `c` that call `add` for each element your code doesn't work. So changing the base class will change the behaviour of your derived class.

Comment: OK, good answer. I was now aware of this pattern. Unfortunatelly, I need to change constructor behavior to provide late initialization. But wrapped class has no default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In case of CorsHandler, I would go with extending the Impl and overriding the handling method:

```
class MyCorsHandler extends CorsHandlerImpl {

    public MyCorsHandler(String allowedOriginPattern) {
        super(allowedOriginPattern);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext context) {
        HttpServerRequest request = context.request();
        HttpServerResponse response = context.response();
        String origin = context.request().headers().get(ORIGIN);
        if (origin == null) {
            // Not a CORS request - we don't set any headers and just call the next handler
            context.next();
        } else if (isMyValidOrigin(origin)) {
            context.next();
        } else {
            super.handle(context);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyValidOrigin(String origin) {
        // Do something there
        return false;
    }
}
```